# function off () cancel click for all elements

Tags: jquery, document

I have a piece of code:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on("click", ".product-image-mobile .product-image", function (e) {
        $(this).attr('data-num', 1);
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).attr("data-num") == 1){
             $(document).off("click", ".product-image-mobile .product-image");
        }
    });
});
```

First click on product image display another image, another click go to product page.
Products loading via ajax.
For first product image this code is working, for others not. I think it concerned $(document).off, which cancel click "prevent" for all other elements.

Please advice how it can be done. Thanks.

Comment: uhhh what? please elaborate

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by unbinding the click event for document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [Attribute value selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to bind event.

```
$(document).on("click", ".product-image-mobile .product-image:not([data-num='1'])", function (e) {
    $(this).attr('data-num', 1);
    e.preventDefault();        
});
```

---

I am not sure, but I think you can also do using

```
    if ($(this).attr("data-num") == 1){
         $(event.target).off("click");
    }
```

Comment: Than's a lot! Forgot about this solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could just extend your selector to no longer select elements with the attribute `data-num="1"` like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).on("click", ".product-image-mobile .product-image[data-num!='1']", function (e) {
        $(this).attr('data-num', 1);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

See also: [attribute-not-equal-selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-not-equal-selector/)

Comment: Than's a lot! Forgot about this solution!